# Glimpse EF6: first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Tags: entity-framework, glimpse

The following code is throwing the first chance exception:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
        try
        {
            var module = _module.ODataQueryable().SingleOrDefault(m => m.ModuleId == id);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, module);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.ErrorException("Error adding module", ex);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
        }
}
```

If we replace the `id` variable with a hard coded int value eg 34 then the code runs.

The source of the exception is `Glimpse.EF6` and the stacktrace is:

```
   at Glimpse.EF.AlternateType.GlimpseDbProviderServices.SetDbParameterValue(DbParameter parameter, TypeUsage parameterType, Object value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.SetParameterValue(DbParameter parameter, TypeUsage parameterType, Object value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.SyncParameterProperties(EntityParameter entityParameter, DbParameter storeParameter, DbProviderServices storeProviderServices)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.PrepareEntityCommandBeforeExecution(EntityCommand entityCommand)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
   at Denarii.Issuing.Web.ClientPortal.Api.ModuleController.Get(Int32 id) in c:\Projects\Denarii.Issuing\Denarii.Issuing.Web.ClientPortal\Api\ModuleController.cs:line 64
```

Do I need to debug the Glimpse EF6 plugin? The module service (_module) works when called from a WinForms app or a console app. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: The module service is using the Repository and UnitOfWorkPattern https://genericunitofworkandrepositories.codeplex.com/

Comment: using the following line of code results in the same exception being throw:  var module = _module.Query(m => m.ModuleId == id).Select().SingleOrDefault();
using the following line of code the exception is not thrown however this line evaluates the condition after all rows have been selected from the the datasource :   var module = _module.Query().Select().SingleOrDefault(m => m.ModuleId == id);  The exception is definitely occurring in Glimpse as the exception is no longer thrown after uninstalling Glimpse from the project.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're talking about is a known issue that you can find [here](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/766) on the Glimpse issues list.

Feel free to add additional information that might help solving the issue

UPDATE: [The issue](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/issues/766) has been fixed by @anthonyv in the meanwhile

Comment: Last night I tried starting with a brand new mvc web project solution using the Northwind database.  Everything was working working fine until I installed Glipmse after which none of the database queries worked.  I started to receive an error Provider.  I will update later with exact error message.  Here at work the basic SQL works.  Here is a picture showing that the SQL tab is working  <a href="http://tinypic.com?ref=6hl18l" target="_blank"><img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/6hl18l.jpg" border="0" alt="Image and video hosting by TinyPic"></a>.

Comment: I think there is a bug with the latest version of Glimpse.  When installing Glimpse the web.config is modified however I think the installer is failing to add the following into the <configSection> of web.config <section name="glimpse" type="Glimpse.Core.Configuration.Section, Glimpse.Core" />

Comment: @jlurie Glimpse uses a web.config.transform that is handled by NuGet, if something is missing in your configuration then it is most likely NuGet related. There is not much we can do than have that section registered in the web.config.transform file

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: On my new Northwind project I installed Glimpse Core, Glimpse.Ado, Glimpse.AspNet, Glimpse.EF6, Glimpse.Mvc and I am using Entity Framework 6.1 and I get the following error:  T
"

Comment: the error I get is"the provider did not return a ProviderManifestTokenString